# Can you flash a Gateway D945GCL BIOS with the Intel version?

Tags: motherboard, bios, updates

I have a motherboard which is model D945GCL. It says Intel Desktop Board on it, however it has a Gateway OEM BIOS version on it currently and originally came from a Gateway machine.

Is this identical to Intel's version of the board in that I can flash the BIOS provided by Intel for this specific model onto the motherboard? (Specifically: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/14364/BIOS-Update-CL94510J-86A-?product=24972) safely? Or will this result in a brick?

Edit: Also, it seems that a Pentium 4 processor that I believe should work in this motherboard causes it to display a message that it is unsupported when I start the computer up, however doesn't the fact that the BIOS is even running suggest that this processor is compatible? Would switching to Intel's retail BIOS enable this processor to work?

Comment: It is not identical.  No; The firmware is detecting an incompatible processor, it's basically failing, a POST test.

Comment: Ok thanks! - would it be okay to use the drivers provided by Intel with this board, since it is the same model number and even says Intel Desktop Board on it, and use a BIOS version from Gateway?

Comment: Try the drivers they either will work or won't work